# Is there any difference between SSL HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https

This question seems pretty dumb, since I always thought it is the same. However I received connectivity details from a service I contracted, and took a picture:

[image: Look at the brushed text]

For legal reasons of the service, I obfuscated most of the data. URLs in the spreadsheet cells look like: "api-ec-dev.thedomain.net:port1/path/to/service" and "api-ec-dev.thedomain.net:port2/path/to/service". There's no accident nor omission here: the cells did not include any schema.

If you look at the brushed text - in the test environment section - you'll notice both "SSL HTTP" and "HTTPS", althought HTTPS url seems empty.

What's the difference? I HAVE to hit such urls with SOAP/PHP. How should I refer the so-called SSL HTTP URL?

Comment: not sure but I think https can use ssl or tls. Maybe you should ask to the guy who wrote the sheet

Comment: HTTPS can use SSL and Implicit TLS (if both parties agree to it), but not Explicit TLS.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

"SSL HTTP" and "HTTPS" are the same thing.  I don't know why the spreadsheet separates them.  It probably should have said "URL HTTP" instead of "URL SSL HTTP" in the first cell.  Without actually seeing the spreadsheet in action, I can only guess that it probably puts `http://` and schema-less URLs in the first cell and `https://` URLs in the second cell.

Comment: I will wait until they answer me. I did not put that "in action" yet.